# R 2.15.1; Rhipe 0.73; CDH 5 - java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs

Tags: java, r, hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I had installed CDH5 on Debian 7. I have working Hadoop with MapReduce1 in Single Node Pseudo-distributed Mode.

I would like to run Rhipe inside R. After downloading I had installed it:

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL Rhipe_0.73.1.tar.gz
```

Then I exported environment variables:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/etc/hadoop/conf"
export HADOOP="/usr/lib/hadoop"
export HADOOP_BIN=/usr/lib/hadoop/bin
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop
```

After running R:

```
> library(Rhipe)
------------------------------------------------
| Please call rhinit() else RHIPE will not run |
------------------------------------------------
> rhinit()
Rhipe: Using Rhipe.jar file
Initializing Rhipe v0.73
14/04/11 12:21:08 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:167)
    at org.godhuli.rhipe.PersonalServer.run(PersonalServer.java:321)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.NullPointerException
>
```

**I am missing something?**

Java used in system:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/j2sdk1.7-oracle/jre/bin/java        317       manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
```

Comment: Can you run command `hadoop class path` and see whether the result contains hadoop-hdfs-*.jar file.

Comment: @donut `damian@cdh5-singleOldMR:~$ hadoop class path`, result:`Error: Could not find or load main class class`.

Comment: sorry my fault the command is `hadoop classpath`

Comment: @donut hehe, I'm java noob, so I didn't even saw that mistake ;). Correct output: `/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//*` there are some hdfs files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rhinit() function is trying to load hadoop jars that are present in directory specified in HADOOP_HOME variable.Since this function only load those jars in HADOOP_HOME to the class path you have to keep all hadoop specific jars in that directory itself.

You can understand this if you look into **zzz.R** file in rhipe package.

Comment: I have created symlink with `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs.jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs.jar` and I currently have other error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/FileOutputFormat`. And it look like different type of error :/

Comment: Can you add symlink for hadoop-core*.jar and all other jars in `hadoop classpath` command

Comment: Ok, I did: 'sudo ln -s /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/* /usr/lib/hadoop` and `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/* /usr/lib/hadoop`. It now looks like no error with hadoop/java, but with Protocol Buffer, despite I have version 2.4.1 from Debian repos: `Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is supposed to be overridden by subclasses.`

Comment: For this issue you can look into this mail list https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/rhipe/eL_2H5tNi4c/UGJgXVAx_QgJ